# Left Join, Union Select with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables with same-named columns, I want to select users distinctly from these all tables (no repeat)
here is my query and it works,

```
SELECT User FROM Table1 UNION SELECT User FROM Table2 UNION SELECT User FROM Table3
```

How do I add another column to Select

something like this,

```
SELECT User, Time
```

But I only need to union on **User** column, **Time** column just for view purpose only.

Update: Here are the 3 tables I have. I want to get user names from these tables without repeating (distinct). and I want the time column to show in result

```
User  | Time     
Sam   | 12.00      
Jack  | 12.00      
Harry | 12.00      
John  | 12.00    
John  | 12.00    
Sam   | 12.00   

User    | Time     
Jacob   | 12.00      
Jack    | 12.00      
Harry   | 12.00      
John    | 12.00    
Charlie | 12.00    
Sam     | 12.00   

User    | Time     
Mason   | 12.00      
William | 12.00      
Harry   | 12.00      
John    | 12.00    
Charlie | 12.00    
Sam     | 12.00
```

The result should be like this:

```
User    | Time     
Mason   | 12.00      
William | 12.00      
Harry   | 12.00      
John    | 12.00    
Charlie | 12.00    
Sam     | 12.00 
Jacob   | 12.00 
Jack    | 12.00
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear because you never gave us the logic for how duplicate `Time` values should be resolved.  Please add some sample input and output data to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sounds like your actual data, unlike your sample, has different timestamps for each user in the different tables, and you don't care *which* of those timestamps is picked as long as the user names are unique...

```
SELECT User, min(Time)
FROM (SELECT User, Time FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT User, Time FROM Table2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT User, Time FROM Table3)
GROUP BY User;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data implies that the `Time` value is always the same, and therefore you don't mind picking any value in the table.  One option here would be to just select a constant value as the `Time` value:

```
SELECT User, '12.00' AS Time FROM Table1 UNION ALL
SELECT User, '12.00' FROM Table2 UNION ALL
SELECT User, '12.00' FROM Table3
```

Comment: what if the `time` value change somehow?

Comment: Then your question is not well founded, in which case you should address the comments given above some time ago.

Comment: I'm Sorry it's my mistake. I want the result without focusing on the time column. time can be anything. but no effect on the result. that's why I add the same time to all the rows.

Comment: Then just select a constant and call it `Time`.